# Bag of words in VADER NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, sentiment-analysis, vader

I've been reading up on VADER as an alternative to Naive Bayes for sentiment analysis. I understand how to retrieve a bag of words using NB model;

```
from nltk import FreqDist
f = FreqDist(movie_reviews.words())
f.most_common()[:X]
```

Is there a way that I could achieve the same output using VADER instead?

Answer (score 0):

VADER does not support the functionality to produce a bag of words from a block of text, it instead focuses on calculating the sentiment accuracy and intensity.

To achieve a bag of words, use;

```
import nltk
from nltk import FreqDist
```